# jQuery - how to add divs to a specific place in the list to an existing list of items with same classes (append)

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

Hi there i have existing list of items. I would like to add to the inside of list one DIV for using bootstrap expand/collapse feature.

I would like to add div after 3 items and link on last position in the list.

Check for the comment tags in my html code to understand where to insert.

Thank you!!

```
<div id="list">
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>

        <!-- there is place for new DIV (after 3 items) -->
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <!-- there is place for end DIV -->

        <!-- there is place for LINK (last position) -->
        <a href="" class="collapse show">Show</a>
        <!-- there is place end LINK -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I totally can't understand your requirement. So, you want to add a class after div 3?

Comment: Sorry for my english :) I want to add "wrapper div" from 10th item (from 10th. item all divs wrap to the new div with class "wrapper") + add at the end of div with id #list "a href link".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if I understood you right. You want to wrap some of the divs with a container to hide them and show them only, if the link was clicked?

```
// Add the collapse wrapper above the link
$('<div class="collapse-wrapper"></div>').insertAfter($("#list > .item").last());

// Loop through items
$('#list > .item').each(function(index){
    // Move all items after the third one to the collapse-wrapper
    if(index >= 3) {
        $(this).appendTo('#list .collapse-wrapper');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$('#list').append('<div class="item">some content</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">some content</div>
  <div class="item">some content</div>
  <div class="item">some content</div>

  <!-- there is place for new DIV (after 3 items) -->
  <div class="item">some content</div>
  <div class="item">some content</div>
  <div class="item">some content</div>
  <div class="item">some content</div>
  <!-- there is place for end DIV -->

  <!-- there is place for LINK (last position) -->
  <a href="" class="collapse show">Show</a>
  <!-- there is place end LINK -->
</div>
```

Comment: no no, I have this list. Now i want "item" from 10. wrap to the div. And create "a href link" on last position in #list

Comment: I don't understand. can you write down the DOM shape you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Araba</h2>
  <div class="inner">Merhaba</div>
  <div class="inner">Gule gule</div>
</div>
```

This code is also for adding where you want

```
$( "<p>Deneme</p>" ).append( ".inner" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('<div class="item">Test</div>').insertAfter($("#list > .item").last());
```

It will insert the div with the class item anter the last element with the class item in the #list element.

Comment: Thank you, With this script I add link with "Show more". And how I add "wrapper div"  from 10. items?

All "div items" from 10. I want wrapped to the div.

Comment: Ah sorry, i misunderstood your request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to wrap the content, for wrap you can do like this.

```js
$('#list > div:nth-child(n+3)').wrapAll('<div></div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>

        <!-- there is place for new DIV (after 3 items) -->
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <div class="item">some content</div>
        <!-- there is place for end DIV -->

        <!-- there is place for LINK (last position) -->
        <a href="" class="collapse show">Show</a>
        <!-- there is place end LINK -->
</div>
```